# WordPress theme options not saving options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently building a WordPress theme with a Theme Options page. I used the original WordPress Theme (Twenty Twelve) as a basis and just adjusted and added as I went along. The problem I ran into is that the page does seem to save my default settings, but when I change them in the form and hit the save button, it still only pulls up the defaults.

This is my theme-options.php, originally in Pastebin but the link has expired, that is included in my functions.php.

Comment: The pastebin.com link has expired.  This question should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not consistent with your naming, change `fatum_box_one` in your options array to `eerste_box`, etc., and change the names of your textareas from `fatum_box_one[eerste_box]` to `fatum_theme_options[eerste_box]`, etc..

Comment: Ah, I knew it had something to do with the naming, but I couldn't put my finger on it. Thank you!